# Regex look around - Java

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have inherited some regex and trying to understand why does it match certain pattern. Following regex is based on positive look-ahead assertion and matching text like `bear grylls episode`. This make sense. But it also matches text where `episode` is followed by `bear grylls`, e.g. `episode bear grylls`. I do not see any reference to look backward in the regex. is `.*?` at the end making it to look backward?

```
^(?=.*?bear grylls)(?=.*?(\bnbc\b|reality|episode|show|watch|series|season|premiere)).*?
```

Comment: take a look at http://regex101.com, this gives proper explanation for the regex as you type it

Answer (score 0):

This explains what its doing.
To modify, It depends on what you want to do.

This is what its currently doing -

```
 # ^(?=.*?bear\ grylls)(?=.*?(\bnbc\b|reality|episode|show|watch|series|season|premiere)).*?

 ^                             # Beginning of string
 (?=                           # Look ahead
      .*?                           # Ungreedy, any number of characters
      bear\ grylls                  # Must be 'bear grylls' somewhere
 )                             # End lookahead
 (?=                           # Look ahead
      .*?                           # Ungreedy, any number of characters
      (                             # (1 start), Must be one of these somewhere
           \b nbc \b 
        |  reality
        |  episode
        |  show
        |  watch
        |  series
        |  season
        |  premiere
      )                             # (1 end)
 )                             # End lookahead
 .*?                           # Assertions passed tests, now match the entire string
```

I would modify it to this to get a little better functionality -

```
 # (?s)^(?=.*\bbear\ grylls\b)(?=.*\b(nbc|reality|episode|show|watch|series|season|premiere)\b).*

 (?s)                          # Dot all modifier
 ^                             # Beginning of string
 (?=                           # Look ahead
      .*                            # Greedy, any number of characters
      \b bear\ grylls \b            # Must be 'bear grylls' 
 )                             # End lookahead
 (?=                           # Look ahead
      .*                            # Greedy, any number of characters
      \b 
      (                             # (1 start), Must be one of these
           nbc 
        |  reality
        |  episode
        |  show
        |  watch
        |  series
        |  season
        |  premiere
      )                             # (1 end)
      \b 
 )                             # End lookahead
 .*                            # Assertions passed tests, now match the entire string
```

I suggest using [RegexFormat 5](http://www.regexformat.com) where it formats and creates auto-comments.

Comment: Thanks Sln. 

How would replacing .?* with .* help ? Isn't the greedy match more expensive than lazy match ?

Comment: Its cheaper by quite a bit. In assertions, avoid using this `.*?` construct if you can.

Answer (score 0):

All look-ahead and look-behind assertions `(?=...)`, `(?!...)`, `(?<=...)`, `(?<!...)` **does not consume text**. It does not advance the pointer to current position, which is the normal behavior when some text is matched.

Since it does not advance the index, you can make use of this property to check several properties of the text, which otherwise would be hard to combine into a single expression without look-ahead.

In your case, the regex checks for the existence of the string `bear grylls`, then it check for the existence of any of the string in the second look-ahead.

Without look-ahead, the regex would become:

```
^.*?bear grylls.*?(\bnbc\b|reality|episode|show|watch|series|season|premiere)|^.*?(\bnbc\b|reality|episode|show|watch|series|season|premiere).*?bear grylls
```

Since `bear grylls` can come before **or** after any of the strings in the list, you need to check both cases in alternation. The DRY problem can be resolve by string concatenation, but when it is not available, people are going to have a hard time with maintenance.

This is also a technique frequently used in password validation, where there can be several conditions, such as at least one alphabet, at least one digit, at least one special character, no 3 same characters in a row, etc. If you want to write a single expression to check all of the properties above, it is extremely messy. Using look-ahead assertion allows you to cram everything in a single expression without making the regex incomprehensible and unmaintainable.

Personally, I'm not too fond of this approach, since there is no point in cramming everything into a single regex, unless you are limited by the tool and are not allowed to run multiple regex. We can just make 2 regex and test the string against each. The performance would be roughly the same, since the same amount of work is done in the regex engine. In fact, I believe most engines would rescan the string twice in the regex above.

Comment: Thanks nhahtdh, this clarifies the confusion about position. 

If I understand correctly look-ahead is cheaper compare to 2nd option. correct me if its not true.

Comment: @KaushalPatel: Which 2nd option? If you are talking about the long regex without look-ahead, then it might be true. But if you are talking about using multiple regex, then both should be more or less the same.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite your original regex, which can have your desired result

```
^(?=.*?bear grylls).+(?=.*?(\bnbc\b|reality|episode|show|watch|series|season|premiere)).*?
```

It is quite similar to the previous one. The only difference is that I add ".+" between the two positive lookahead assertion, which will enforce the sequence of these two parts, e.g., "bear grylls episode" will have positive result while "episode bear grylls" won't.

Without this, these two lookahead assertion won't have any sequence preference. Basically they are completely equal.

Comment: This doesn't do what you think it will. `^(?=.*?bear grylls)` still matches anywhere in the string.